# Linphone SDK 5 IOS

Tags: ios, swift, call, record, linphone

Hello every one im using  Linphone IOS SDK 5 to build app for sip calls
everything is fine
now i want do feature to record calls
i created path for records

```
func outgoingCall(to number: String, name: String?) {
        phone = number
        self.name = name
        do {
            // As for everything we need to get the SIP URI of the remote and convert it to an Address
            // We also need a CallParams object
            // Create call params expects a Call object for incoming calls, but for outgoing we must use null safely
            let params = try mCore.createCallParams(call: nil)
            // We can now configure it
            // Here we ask for no encryption but we could ask for ZRTP/SRTP/DTLS
            params.mediaEncryption = MediaEncryption.None
            
            params.recordFile = getWhistleURL().absoluteString
            // If we wanted to start the call with video directly
            //params.videoEnabled = true
            // Finally we start the call
            mCall = mCore.inviteWithParams(url: number, params: params)
            // Call process can be followed in onCallStateChanged callback from core listener
        } catch { NSLog(error.localizedDescription) }
        
    }
```

then i check if is recording by print(call.isRecording) im getting true

but when i stop call and start to get file by path and play it i getting empty file by path my player cant play it because file doesnt exist
i tried my recorder and is work fine but dosent record remote caller voice
please any help